# Pandas: get some data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe `ID,"month","type"
0896cbe25bb8aec86ff93dd1bf20fa80,2013-12,desktop
0896cbe25bb8aec86ff93dd1bf20fa80,2014-01,desktop
0896cbe25bb8aec86ff93dd1bf20fa80,2014-02,desktop
0896cbe25bb8aec86ff93dd1bf20fa80,2014-03,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-06,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-07,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-08,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-09,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-10,desktop`

And have another dataframe

```
idp year    month
5663b84ee164ed2628f4df6ed6ffe89b    2015    11
d156e747fb3e715a13ac850ca3e4c0e5    2014    7
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014    10
142068cd70ec3541698c919b023caf1c    2014    3
24fa9c75cc86187937f4fea0c06a6513    2014    12
3e3906343b235e6eac743be65da1dcbb    2014    6
757bf2f08a1de8383e24509d5f105ce7    2015    8
```

I need if `idp` in first dataframe and if date from second df is equal to first (or month from first df less to 1 from second month) I should get data to this ID.
I need to get

```
ID, month, type
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-06,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-07,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-08,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-09,desktop
0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a,2014-10,desktop
```

How can I write this condition?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll be very effective on big dataframes, 
but you may add a special "merge" column to df2:

```
    >>> df2['year_month'] =  df2.year.astype(str) + '-'  + df2.month.astype(int).apply(lambda s: '%02d' % s)
    >>> df2
                            idp  year  month year_month
    0  5663b84ee164ed2628f4df6ed6ffe89b  2015     11    2015-11
    1  d156e747fb3e715a13ac850ca3e4c0e5  2014      7    2014-07
    2  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a  2014     10    2014-10
    3  142068cd70ec3541698c919b023caf1c  2014      3    2014-03
    4  24fa9c75cc86187937f4fea0c06a6513  2014     12    2014-12
    5  3e3906343b235e6eac743be65da1dcbb  2014      6    2014-06
    6  757bf2f08a1de8383e24509d5f105ce7  2015      8    2015-08
```

[Merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) and [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query) to take only interesting rows and columns:

```
    >>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='ID', right_on='idp', suffixes=('', '_df2')) \
          .query('month <= year_month') \
          [df1.columns]
                             id year_month     type
    4  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014-06  desktop
    5  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014-07  desktop
    6  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014-08  desktop
    7  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014-09  desktop
    8  0ce926c4c33e63aeef04a55dc204cb1a    2014-10  desktop
```

Comment: can you say, how can I all strings with this id?

Comment: One more time, pls. What do you need? Filter df1 and show only rows with corresponding id==idp and month==year '- 'month?  Or smth else?

Comment: Ohhh. I've misunderstood you.  I've updated the solution to take several rows not one. Take a look pls.

Comment: And how can write a condition, if month - 1 from second df is equal to month from first df, use too?

Comment: Like in Databases:  `year_month <= year_month_df2`. Here `year_month` from first `df1` is compared to `year_month` from second `df2`. Note after `merge` all columns with equal names get suffixes. So `year_month` from df2 becomes `year_month_df2`.

Comment: Я рекомендую почитать про методы merge и query (ссылки выше). `.query()` работает примерно как условие WHERE в SELECT для баз данных - отбирает только те строки, где это выражение верно.

Comment: Первая строка не работает `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ' '`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121173/discussion-between-eugene-lisitsky-and-ldevyataykina).

Comment: а еще такой вопрос: вторая строчка возвращает ошибку pandas.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'year_month_df2' is not defined
что такое year_month_df2?